# How to add auto increment in a model before migrating to database?

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a model that will create a table with Core Identity. I want to add extra column 'UserID' with an auto-increment property.

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    [Column(TypeName="Nvarchar(150)")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int UserRoleID { get; set; }

}
```

this is my model

Answer (score 0):

You could use Fluent Api Configuration:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
   public override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
         modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .Property(f => f.UserId)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
   }
}
```